# uploading same file multiple times parallely

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

my test website html part is below:

```
<button id="btnUpload" type="button" class="btn fileinput-button fileinputs">
    <span class="icon wc-upload"></span>
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple=""></button>
```

Now to upload file, i am using the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#btnUpload")).sendKeys(AppConstant.RESOURCE_DIR+fileName);
```

but it upload the same file multiple times parallely. But if i do this manually, the selected file uploaded only once.

WHat is the solution here???

Comment: Have you need to click on any button where you are clicking multiple times?

Comment: no i dont need to click on any button.

Comment: Have you tried with passing the absolute path of image instead AppConstant.RESOURCE_DIR .. try it once

Comment: shows the same problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#btnUpload")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CLEAR));
```

Put this code after your uploading file code

Hope it will help you

Comment: I use python with selenium and faced with the same problem. Could please explain how your solution works? And what is chord?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `sendkeys()` on the `WebElement` corresponding to your `<input type="file">` as:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(AppConstant.RESOURCE_DIR+fileName);
```

-OR-

```
WebElement inputFileControl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))
inputFileControl.sendKeys(AppConstant.RESOURCE_DIR+fileName);
```